# NSuserdefaults App group Location

Tags: ios, iphone

Where can I find the location for NSUserDefaults with App Group setting saved in iPhone simulator or devices? I can find location for NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults but not with App Group setting. Hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Location of UserDefaults app group are stored at below path

> /Users/{USER_NAME}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{UUID}/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/{UUID}/Library/Preferences/{GROUP_NAME}.plist

Comment: thank you! found it! Do you know how I can find it for devices?